# Rails 3 - Controller Def Update, is not updating the record & Not erroring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's is my permissions controller for DEF UPDATE:

```
def update

  @permission = Permission.where(:user_id=> params[:permission][:user_id] ).where(:project_id=> params[:permission][:project_id]).first

  respond_to do |format|
    if @permission.update_attributes( params[:role_id] )
        format.js  { render :layout => false }
    else
        format.js  { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

**Form Post Header**
utf8:✓
_method:put
authenticity_token:17rvYJmq7167 ktDBXZgDnopH3QY/Tb5a3K0jtcTjrU=
permission%5Brole_id%5D:3
permission%5Buser_id%5D:11
permission%5Bproject_id%5D:3

No errors here, but the role_id is not being updated? Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `params[:role_id]` as the parameter to update_attributes, but this isn't set according to the post data you included.

I think what you probably mean is this:

```
if @permission.update_attribute(:role_id, params[:permission][:role_id])
    ...
end
```

Comment: Strange. that errors: "NoMethodError (undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/permissions_controller.rb:46:in `update'
  app/controllers/permissions_controller.rb:45:in `update'
"

Comment: Full debugger log: "(rdb:31) @permission
#<Permission project_id: 3, role_id: 2, user_id: 11>
(rdb:31) params[:permission][:role_id]
"1"
(rdb:31) @permission.update_attribute(:role_id, params[:permission][:role_id])
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
(rdb:31) 
"

Comment: Which line is 46? Note that I changed update_attributes to update_attribute in my code sample.

Comment: @Tim, thanks it's update_attribute not attributes in the code now. "   46  
   47      respond_to do |format|
   48        if @permission.update_attribute(:role_id, params[:permission][:role_id])
   49        format.js  { render :layout => false }
"

Comment: is it bec this table has no ID? (rdb:31) @permission.id
nil

Comment: Ah, yes, that'd do it. Simplest solution might be to destroy the record and create a new one.

Comment: ahh shoot. really? Should I add an ID to this table? even though it's a Y-Model, for Projects, Roles, Users?

Comment: Yup, id would make things easier too. Normally for lookup tables you can just use HABTM, but as soon as you need extra fields you need a model for it. See http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off for a detailed write up.